# Some lines are formatted differently (overflowing) for a reason I can't tell

Tags: line-breaking, margins

In my first attempt to use LaTeX a bit seriously, I formatted my CV using the template in ShareLaTeX.  Some parts were confusing and I got some great help from here and finally produced a CV that looks very pleasing to my eye.

Recently, I decided to enter doi information for my publications manually (I don't use bibTeX or any other reference manager for the CV; all of it is manual) and unfortunately, some of the lines overflow whereas the rest stick to the proper margin.  I'm not sure why and how to fix.

Please let me know if you can figure it out.  I thank all who try to help in advance.  Code and example of a problematic line follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 

\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[
  bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks, 
  % ---- FILL IN HERE THE TITLE AND AUTHOR
  pdftitle={S. Adil Sarıbay - vita},
  pdfauthor={S. Adil Sarıbay},
  pdfproducer={http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex}
]{hyperref}  

% FONTS
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[
  Ligatures={Common}, Numbers={OldStyle}, Variant=01,
  BoldFont=LinLibertine_RB.otf,
  ItalicFont=LinLibertine_RI.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=LinLibertine_RBI.otf
]{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{DejaVuSansMono.ttf}

% ---- SETTINGS
\geometry{a4paper, textwidth=5.5in, textheight=8.5in, marginparsep=7pt, marginparwidth=.6in}
\setlength\parindent{0in}
\linespread{1.03} %Adil added this to change linespacing, default is 1
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=MidnightBlue} 

% ---- CUSTOM COMMANDS
\chardef\&="E050
\newcommand{\html}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[html]}}}
\newcommand{\pdf}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[pdf]}}}
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[doi]}}}
% ---- MARGIN YEARS
\newcommand{\amper{}}{\chardef\amper="E0BD }
\newcommand{\years}[1]{%
  \par\leavevmode\marginnote{\scriptsize #1}\ignorespaces
}
\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{7pt}
\reversemarginpar

% HEADINGS
\sectionfont{\mdseries\upshape\Large}
\subsectionfont{\mdseries\scshape\normalsize} 
\subsubsectionfont{\mdseries\upshape\large} 

% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
{\LARGE Selahattin Adil Sarıbay}\newline

Boğaziçi University

Department of Psychology

Bebek, Istanbul, \texttt{34342,} TURKEY\newline

Phone: \texttt{+90-212-3596584}

Fax: \texttt{+90-212-2872472}\newline

email: \href{mailto:adil.saribay@boun.edu.tr}{adil.saribay@boun.edu.tr}

\textsc{url}: \href{http://www.psychology.boun.edu.tr/AdilSaribay}{http://www.psychology.boun.edu.tr/AdilSaribay}\newline

Born:  September 8, 1978---Bursa, Turkey

Nationality:  Turkish

Language Proficiency: Turkish (native), English (native-like fluency)

%%\hrule
\section*{Appointments held}
\noindent
\years{2013-present}Associate Professor, Department of Psychology,  Boğaziçi University
\years{2010-2013}Assistant Professor, Department of Psychology, Boğaziçi University
\years{2008-2010}Postdoctoral Fellow, Bremen International Graduate School of Social Sciences
\years{2002-2007} Graduate Assistant, New York University
\years{2000-2002} Graduate Assistant, Istanbul Bilgi University

%\hrule
\section*{Education}
\noindent
\years{2002-2008}\textsc{Ph.D.} in Social/Personality Psychology, New York University
\years{2000-2002}\textsc{M.A.} in Psychological Sciences, Boğaziçi University
\years{1996-2000}\textsc{B.S.} in Psychology, Middle East Technical University

\begingroup\setlength\parskip{1ex} %Adil=create space between reference items by hitting enter here in the code

\section*{Publications}
\subsection*{Journal articles}
\years{2015} Günsoy, C., Cross, S. E., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Olcaysoy-Okten, I., \& Kurutaş, M. (2015).  Would you post that picture and let your dad see it? Culture, honor, and Facebook. \emph{European Journal of Social Psychology, 45 (3),} 323-335. doi:10.1002/ejsp.2041 [SSCI]
\years{2012} \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Rim, S., \& Uleman, J. S. (2012).  Primed self-construal, culture, and stages of impression formation. \emph{Social Psychology [Special Issue on Culture as Process], 43 (4),} 196-204. doi:10.1027/1864-9335/a000120 [SSCI]

Uleman, J. S., Rim, S., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Kressel, L. (2012).  Controversies, questions, and prospects for spontaneous social inferences. \emph{Social and Personality Psychology Compass, 6 (9),} 657-673. doi:10.1111/j.1751-9004.2012.00452.x
\years{2008} Andersen, S. M., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Thorpe, J. S. (2008).  Simple kindness can go a long way:  Relationships, social identity, and engagement. \emph{Social Psychology [Special Issue: Social Psychology and Peace], 39 (1),} 59-69. doi:10.1027/1864-9335.39.1.59 [SSCI]

Uleman, J. S., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Gonzalez, C. M. (2008).  Spontaneous inferences, implicit impressions, and implicit theories.  \emph{Annual Review of Psychology, 59,} 329-360. doi:10.1146/annurev.psych.59.103006.093707 [SSCI]
\years{2007}\textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Andersen, S. M. (2007).  Relational to collective:  Significant-other representations, ethnic categories, and intergroup perceptions.  \emph{Personality and Social Psychology Bulletin, 33 (12),} 1714-1726. doi: 10.1177/0146167207307486 [SSCI]

\textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Andersen, S. M. (2007).  Are past relationships at the heart of attachment dynamics?:  What love has to do with it.  \emph{Psychological Inquiry, 18 (3),} 183-191. doi:10.1080/10478400701512786 [SSCI]

\subsection*{Book chapters}
\years{2015} \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Olcaysoy-Okten, I., \& Yılmaz, O. (2015).  İdeolojik yönelimler ve psikolojik değişkenler. \emph{Siyaset Psikolojisi} (1. Cilt, s. 1-46), Editör: Özlem Dirilen Gümüş. Ankara: Nobel Yayınları.
\years{2013} Chen, S., Boucher, H., Andersen, S. M., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (2013).  Transference and the relational self.  In J. A. Simpson \& L. Campbell (Eds.), \emph{The Oxford Handbook of Close Relationships} (pp. 281-305).  New York: Oxford University Press.
\years{2012} Andersen, S. M., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Przybylinski, E. (2012).  Social cognition in close relationships.  In S. T. Fiske \& N. Macrae (Eds.), \emph{The SAGE Handbook of Social Cognition} (pp. 350-371). Thousand Oaks, CA: SAGE.

Andersen, S. M., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (2012).  Brainwashing and totalitarian influence.  In V.  S. Ramachandran (Ed.), {\it Encyclopedia of Human Behavior} (2nd Ed.) (pp. 406-412). San Diego, CA: Elsevier Academic Press.

Uleman, J. S., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (2012).  Initial impressions of others.  In K. Deaux \& M. Snyder (Eds.), {\it The Oxford handbook of Personality and Social Psychology} (pp. 337-366).  New York: Oxford University Press.
\years{2008} Andersen, S. M., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Kooij, C. S. (2008).  Contextual variability in personality: The case of the relational self and the process of transference.  In F. Rhodewalt (Ed.), \emph{Personality and Social Behavior} (pp. 79-116).  New York: Psychology Press.
\years{2006} Andersen, S. M., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (2006).  Thinking integratively about social psychology:  The example of the relational self and the social-cognitive process of transference.  In P. A. M. van Lange (Ed.), \emph{Bridging Social Psychology} (pp. 199-206). Mahwah, NJ: Lawrence Erlbaum Associates.
\years{2005} Andersen, S. M., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (2005).  The relational self and transference:  Evoking motives, self-regulation, and emotions through activation of mental representations of significant others.  In M. W. Baldwin (Ed.), \emph{Interpersonal Cognition} (pp. 1-32).  New York: Guilford Press.

\section*{Conference Presentations}
\years{2015}Scott, K., Gunsoy, C., Cross, S. E., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Olcaysoy-Okten, I., Kurutas, M.,\& Camorani, G. (May, 2015). Cultural differences in facebook status updates: The role of honor values and fear of envy. Poster presented at the 87th annual meeting of the Midwestern Psychological Association, Chicago, IL.

Yılmaz, O., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (May, 2015). Differentiating political ideologies and conservatism in Turkey in terms of psychological variables. Talk given at Society, Identity, and Politics: Social Psychological Approaches, Istanbul Şehir University, Istanbul, TURKEY.

\textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (May, 2015). The effects of (dis)believing free will on social behavior. Talk given at Kognitif XII, Üsküdar University, Istanbul, TURKEY.
\years{2014} Trebicky, V., Kleisner, K., Kočnar, T., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Valentova, J. V., Varella, M. A. C., \& Havlíček, J. (June, 2014).  Cross-cultural differences in inference of aggressiveness: Testing the other-race effect hypothesis. Talk given at the 22nd biennial international conference on human ethology, Belem, BRAZIL.

Barsbey, M., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Boduroğlu, A., \& Zwaan, R. A. (August, 2014). Perceptual simulations beyond the sentence: The effect of later narrative shifts on perceptual simulations.  Poster presented at the 7th Annual Conference on Embodied and Situated Language Processing, Rotterdam, THE NETHERLANDS.

\textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Przybylinski, E., \& Andersen, S. M. (July, 2014). Activation of a significant other’s social network in transference: Implications for collective identity. Talk given at the 17th General Meeting of the European Association of Social Psychology, Amsterdam, THE NETHERLANDS.

Gunsoy, C., Cross, S. E., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Olcaysoy-Okten, I., \& Kurutas, M. (February, 2014). Would you post that picture and let your dad see it? Culture, Honor and Facebook. Poster presented at the 15th Annual Meeting of the Society for Personality and Social Psychology, Austin, TX.

Olcaysoy-Okten, I., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (February, 2014). The relationship between resistance to change and opposition to equality at political and personal levels. Poster presented at the 15th Annual Meeting of the Society for Personality and Social Psychology, Austin, TX.
\years{2013} Olcaysoy, I., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (January, 2013). Activation of stereotypes and resource depletion in preparation for inter-ideological interaction. Poster presented at the 14th Annual Meeting of the Society for Personality and Social Psychology, New Orleans, LA.
\years{2012} Olcaysoy, I., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (April, 2012). The measurement of resistance to change and opposition to equality dimensions of conservatism at personal and political levels. Poster presented at the 17th National Congress of Psychology, Boğaziçi University, Istanbul, TURKEY.

Rim, S., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Uleman, J. S. (January, 2012).  Dissociable effect of self-esteem threat on intentional and unintentional stereotyping of others. Poster presented at the 13th Annual Conference of the Society for Personality and Social Psychology, San Diego, CA.
\years{2011} \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Rim, S., Kühnen, U., \& Uleman, J. S. (July, 2011).  Culture, self-construals, and their effects on stages of impression formation. Talk given at the International Society for Self and Identity preconference, 16th General Meeting of the European Association of Social Psychology, Stockholm, SWEDEN.

Kühnen, U., Haberstroh, S., Öberst, A., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (January, 2011).  The conversational basis of ease of retrieval effects. Poster presented at the 12th Annual Conference of the Society for Personality and Social Psychology, San Antonio, TX.
\years{2006} \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Andersen, S. M., Kooij, C., \& Schneidmesser, E. (May, 2006).  Significant-other representations influence intergroup perceptions. Poster presented at the 18th Annual Conference of the Association for Psychological Science, New York, NY.

Uleman, J. S., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Rim, S., \& Gorman, J. P. (May, 2006).  Processing goals affect control over the influence of implicit impressions. Poster presented at the 18th Annual Conference of the Association for Psychological Science, New York, NY.

\textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Uleman, J. S., Rim, S., \& Gorman, J. P. (January, 2006).  The imperviousness of behavior interpretations to vague suspicions. Poster presented at the 7th Annual Conference of the Society for Personality and Social Psychology, Palm Springs, CA.
\years{2003} \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Ataca, B. (July, 2003). Individualism-collectivism, self-concept clarity, and self-esteem. Poster presented at the 6th European Regional Congress of the International Association for Cross-Cultural Psychology, Budapest, Hungary.
\years{2001} \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (July, 2001) Kurt Lewin: His metatheory and its evaluation in terms of the ten fundamental issues. Poster presented at the 7th European Congress of Psychology, London, UK.
\endgroup

\section*{Invited Colloquia}
\subsection*{Academic}
\years{2014} Charles University, Prague, CZECH REPUBLIC (October)
\years{2013} 18th National Psychology Students Congress, Izmir University of Economics, TURKEY (July)
\years{2011} Middle East Technical University, TURKEY (June)
\years{2009} Koç University, TURKEY (October)
\years{2008} Columbia Business School, NY, USA (April)

National Chengchi University, Taipei, TAIWAN (April)

Gettysburg College, PA, USA (February)

Hong Kong University of Science and Technology, HONG KONG (February)

Singapore Management University, SINGAPORE (January)

National Cheng-Kung University, Tainan, TAIWAN (January)  

\subsection*{Industry \& Organizations}
\years{2016} Psikolojik açıdan “mobbing”: Tanımı, özellikleri ve oluşma zemini. İş Vereni Yakan Sorular 5, Datassist
\years{2015} Trust and Leadership. EnerjiSA
\years{2014} Sosyal-bilişsel açıdan değerlendirmenin zorluğu. Değerlendiriciler Zirvesi, İş Bankası

\section*{Professional Activities}
\subsection*{Ad-hoc Reviewer}
Basic and Applied Social Psychology, European Journal of Social Psychology, Journal of Community and Applied Social Psychology, Journal of Experimental Social Psychology, Journal of Personality \& Social Psychology, Personality \& Social Psychology Bulletin, Psychonomic Bulletin \& Review, Polish Psychological Bulletin, Scandinavian Journal of Psychology, Self \& Identity, Social Justice Research

\subsection*{Consulting Reviewer}
\years{2013-present} Türk Psikoloji Yazıları [Turkish Psychological Articles]

\subsection*{Grant Reviewer}
\years{2014,2015} Panel Judge and Project Consultant, Scientific and Technological Research Council of Turkey, Social Sciences and Humanities Research Grant Committee (TÜBİTAK-SOBAG)
\years{2013, 2014} External Assessor in Psychology Committee,  Insight Grants Program, SSHRC (Canada)
\years{2013} External Consultant, Scientific and Technological Research Council of Turkey, Social Sciences and Humanities Research Grant Committee (TÜBİTAK-SOBAG)


\subsection*{Committees}
\years{2012} 17th National Congress of Psychology, Administrative Committee \& Scientific Committee Member


\section*{Administrative Duties}

\years{2013-present} Faculty of Arts and Sciences, Faculty Executive Committee, Assoc. Prof. Representative
\years{2011-2015} Psychology Ethics Subcommittee, Executive Member
\years{2012-2015} Department of Psychology, Vice Chair
\years{2013} Faculty of Arts and Sciences, Faculty Council, Asst. Prof. Representative


\section*{Teaching}

Undergraduate: Social Psychology, Experimental Psychology, History of Psychology, Research Methods

Graduate: Social Psychology, Research Methods \& Statistics, Social Psychology of Organizations


%\hrule
\section*{Grants, Honors \& Awards}
\noindent
\years{2013}Excellence in Research Award, BÜVAK (Boğaziçi University Foundation)
\years{2011}Internal research grant, "Psychological Bases of Conservatism," Boğaziçi University
\years{2008-2010}Postdoctoral Fellowship, Bremen International Graduate School of Social Sciences
\years{2002-2007}MacCracken Fellowship, New York University
\years{2000}Ranked 2nd among graduating class, Middle East Technical University

%\vspace{1cm}
\vfill{}
%\hrulefill

\begin{center}
{\scriptsize  Last updated: \today\- •\- 
% ---- PLEASE LEAVE THIS BACKLINK FOR ATTRIBUTION AS PER CC-LICENSE
Typeset in \href{http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex}{
%\fontspec{Times New Roman}
\XeTeX }\\
% ---- FILL IN THE FULL URL TO YOUR CV HERE
\href{http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex}{http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: LaTeX cannot break up that number. You have to force a linereak directly before the doi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:  your given code has nothing to with class `moderncv`, so I deleted the tag `moderncv`.

Second:  Looking at the given code the best practice seems to be to add a linebreak to start the doi number in the next line.  But that yould cause great spaces in the line before.  so the best way is to add also a command `\hfill` to get no big spaces and no warning ...

Change the code to (changes marked with `<=======`):

```
Uleman, J. S., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Gonzalez, C. M. (2008).  Spontaneous inferences, implicit impressions, and implicit theories.  \emph{Annual Review of Psychology, 59,} 329-360. \hfill\\ % <============================================================
doi:10.1146/annurev.psych.59.103006.093707 [SSCI] % <===================
```

Complete MWE (I deleted your fonts, because I have not installed them. But for your problem this does not mattter.):

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 

\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xunicode} % needs XeLaTeX
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage[
  bookmarks, colorlinks, breaklinks, 
  % ---- FILL IN HERE THE TITLE AND AUTHOR
  pdftitle={S. Adil Sarıbay - vita},
  pdfauthor={S. Adil Sarıbay},
  pdfproducer={http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex}
]{hyperref}  

% FONTS
%\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setmainfont[
  %Ligatures={Common}, Numbers={OldStyle}, Variant=01,
  %BoldFont=LinLibertine_RB.otf,
  %ItalicFont=LinLibertine_RI.otf,
  %BoldItalicFont=LinLibertine_RBI.otf
%]{LinLibertine_R.otf}
%\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{DejaVuSansMono.ttf}

% ---- SETTINGS
\geometry{a4paper, textwidth=5.5in, textheight=8.5in, marginparsep=7pt, marginparwidth=.6in}
\setlength\parindent{0in}
\linespread{1.03} %Adil added this to change linespacing, default is 1
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,filecolor=black,urlcolor=MidnightBlue} 

% ---- CUSTOM COMMANDS
\chardef\&="E050
\newcommand{\html}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[html]}}}
\newcommand{\pdf}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[pdf]}}}
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\href{#1}{\scriptsize\textsc{[doi]}}}
% ---- MARGIN YEARS
\newcommand{\amper{}}{\chardef\amper="E0BD }
\newcommand{\years}[1]{%
  \par\leavevmode\marginnote{\scriptsize #1}\ignorespaces
}
\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{7pt}
\reversemarginpar

% HEADINGS
\sectionfont{\mdseries\upshape\Large}
\subsectionfont{\mdseries\scshape\normalsize} 
\subsubsectionfont{\mdseries\upshape\large} 

% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
{\LARGE Selahattin Adil Sarıbay}\newline

Boğaziçi University

Department of Psychology

Bebek, Istanbul, \texttt{34342,} TURKEY\newline

Phone: \texttt{+90-212-3596584}

Fax: \texttt{+90-212-2872472}\newline

email: \href{mailto:adil.saribay@boun.edu.tr}{adil.saribay@boun.edu.tr}

\textsc{url}: \href{http://www.psychology.boun.edu.tr/AdilSaribay}{http://www.psychology.boun.edu.tr/AdilSaribay}\newline

Born:  September 8, 1978---Bursa, Turkey

Nationality:  Turkish

Language Proficiency: Turkish (native), English (native-like fluency)

%%\hrule
\section*{Appointments held}
\noindent
\years{2013-present}Associate Professor, Department of Psychology,  Boğaziçi University
\years{2010-2013}Assistant Professor, Department of Psychology, Boğaziçi University
\years{2008-2010}Postdoctoral Fellow, Bremen International Graduate School of Social Sciences
\years{2002-2007} Graduate Assistant, New York University
\years{2000-2002} Graduate Assistant, Istanbul Bilgi University

%\hrule
\section*{Education}
\noindent
\years{2002-2008}\textsc{Ph.D.} in Social/Personality Psychology, New York University
\years{2000-2002}\textsc{M.A.} in Psychological Sciences, Boğaziçi University
\years{1996-2000}\textsc{B.S.} in Psychology, Middle East Technical University

\begingroup\setlength\parskip{1ex} %Adil=create space between reference items by hitting enter here in the code

\section*{Publications}
\subsection*{Journal articles}
\years{2015} Günsoy, C., Cross, S. E., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Olcaysoy-Okten, I., \& Kurutaş, M. (2015).  Would you post that picture and let your dad see it? Culture, honor, and Facebook. \emph{European Journal of Social Psychology, 45 (3),} 323-335. doi:10.1002/ejsp.2041 [SSCI]
\years{2012} \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Rim, S., \& Uleman, J. S. (2012).  Primed self-construal, culture, and stages of impression formation. \emph{Social Psychology [Special Issue on Culture as Process], 43 (4),} 196-204. doi:10.1027/1864-9335/a000120 [SSCI]

Uleman, J. S., Rim, S., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Kressel, L. (2012).  Controversies, questions, and prospects for spontaneous social inferences. \emph{Social and Personality Psychology Compass, 6 (9),} 657-673. doi:10.1111/j.1751-9004.2012.00452.x
\years{2008} Andersen, S. M., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Thorpe, J. S. (2008).  Simple kindness can go a long way:  Relationships, social identity, and engagement. \emph{Social Psychology [Special Issue: Social Psychology and Peace], 39 (1),} 59-69. doi:10.1027/1864-9335.39.1.59 [SSCI]

Uleman, J. S., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Gonzalez, C. M. (2008).  Spontaneous inferences, implicit impressions, and implicit theories.  \emph{Annual Review of Psychology, 59,} 329-360. \hfill\\ % <============================================================
doi:10.1146/annurev.psych.59.103006.093707 [SSCI] % <===================

\years{2007}\textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Andersen, S. M. (2007).  Relational to collective:  Significant-other representations, ethnic categories, and intergroup perceptions.  \emph{Personality and Social Psychology Bulletin, 33 (12),} 1714-1726. doi: 10.1177/0146167207307486 [SSCI]

\textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Andersen, S. M. (2007).  Are past relationships at the heart of attachment dynamics?:  What love has to do with it.  \emph{Psychological Inquiry, 18 (3),} 183-191. doi:10.1080/10478400701512786 [SSCI]

\subsection*{Book chapters}
\years{2015} \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Olcaysoy-Okten, I., \& Yılmaz, O. (2015).  İdeolojik yönelimler ve psikolojik değişkenler. \emph{Siyaset Psikolojisi} (1. Cilt, s. 1-46), Editör: Özlem Dirilen Gümüş. Ankara: Nobel Yayınları.
\years{2013} Chen, S., Boucher, H., Andersen, S. M., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (2013).  Transference and the relational self.  In J. A. Simpson \& L. Campbell (Eds.), \emph{The Oxford Handbook of Close Relationships} (pp. 281-305).  New York: Oxford University Press.
\years{2012} Andersen, S. M., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Przybylinski, E. (2012).  Social cognition in close relationships.  In S. T. Fiske \& N. Macrae (Eds.), \emph{The SAGE Handbook of Social Cognition} (pp. 350-371). Thousand Oaks, CA: SAGE.

Andersen, S. M., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (2012).  Brainwashing and totalitarian influence.  In V.  S. Ramachandran (Ed.), {\it Encyclopedia of Human Behavior} (2nd Ed.) (pp. 406-412). San Diego, CA: Elsevier Academic Press.

Uleman, J. S., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (2012).  Initial impressions of others.  In K. Deaux \& M. Snyder (Eds.), {\it The Oxford handbook of Personality and Social Psychology} (pp. 337-366).  New York: Oxford University Press.
\years{2008} Andersen, S. M., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Kooij, C. S. (2008).  Contextual variability in personality: The case of the relational self and the process of transference.  In F. Rhodewalt (Ed.), \emph{Personality and Social Behavior} (pp. 79-116).  New York: Psychology Press.
\years{2006} Andersen, S. M., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (2006).  Thinking integratively about social psychology:  The example of the relational self and the social-cognitive process of transference.  In P. A. M. van Lange (Ed.), \emph{Bridging Social Psychology} (pp. 199-206). Mahwah, NJ: Lawrence Erlbaum Associates.
\years{2005} Andersen, S. M., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (2005).  The relational self and transference:  Evoking motives, self-regulation, and emotions through activation of mental representations of significant others.  In M. W. Baldwin (Ed.), \emph{Interpersonal Cognition} (pp. 1-32).  New York: Guilford Press.

\section*{Conference Presentations}
\years{2015}Scott, K., Gunsoy, C., Cross, S. E., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Olcaysoy-Okten, I., Kurutas, M.,\& Camorani, G. (May, 2015). Cultural differences in facebook status updates: The role of honor values and fear of envy. Poster presented at the 87th annual meeting of the Midwestern Psychological Association, Chicago, IL.

Yılmaz, O., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (May, 2015). Differentiating political ideologies and conservatism in Turkey in terms of psychological variables. Talk given at Society, Identity, and Politics: Social Psychological Approaches, Istanbul Şehir University, Istanbul, TURKEY.

\textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (May, 2015). The effects of (dis)believing free will on social behavior. Talk given at Kognitif XII, Üsküdar University, Istanbul, TURKEY.
\years{2014} Trebicky, V., Kleisner, K., Kočnar, T., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Valentova, J. V., Varella, M. A. C., \& Havlíček, J. (June, 2014).  Cross-cultural differences in inference of aggressiveness: Testing the other-race effect hypothesis. Talk given at the 22nd biennial international conference on human ethology, Belem, BRAZIL.

Barsbey, M., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Boduroğlu, A., \& Zwaan, R. A. (August, 2014). Perceptual simulations beyond the sentence: The effect of later narrative shifts on perceptual simulations.  Poster presented at the 7th Annual Conference on Embodied and Situated Language Processing, Rotterdam, THE NETHERLANDS.

\textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Przybylinski, E., \& Andersen, S. M. (July, 2014). Activation of a significant other’s social network in transference: Implications for collective identity. Talk given at the 17th General Meeting of the European Association of Social Psychology, Amsterdam, THE NETHERLANDS.

Gunsoy, C., Cross, S. E., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Olcaysoy-Okten, I., \& Kurutas, M. (February, 2014). Would you post that picture and let your dad see it? Culture, Honor and Facebook. Poster presented at the 15th Annual Meeting of the Society for Personality and Social Psychology, Austin, TX.

Olcaysoy-Okten, I., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (February, 2014). The relationship between resistance to change and opposition to equality at political and personal levels. Poster presented at the 15th Annual Meeting of the Society for Personality and Social Psychology, Austin, TX.
\years{2013} Olcaysoy, I., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (January, 2013). Activation of stereotypes and resource depletion in preparation for inter-ideological interaction. Poster presented at the 14th Annual Meeting of the Society for Personality and Social Psychology, New Orleans, LA.
\years{2012} Olcaysoy, I., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (April, 2012). The measurement of resistance to change and opposition to equality dimensions of conservatism at personal and political levels. Poster presented at the 17th National Congress of Psychology, Boğaziçi University, Istanbul, TURKEY.

Rim, S., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Uleman, J. S. (January, 2012).  Dissociable effect of self-esteem threat on intentional and unintentional stereotyping of others. Poster presented at the 13th Annual Conference of the Society for Personality and Social Psychology, San Diego, CA.
\years{2011} \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Rim, S., Kühnen, U., \& Uleman, J. S. (July, 2011).  Culture, self-construals, and their effects on stages of impression formation. Talk given at the International Society for Self and Identity preconference, 16th General Meeting of the European Association of Social Psychology, Stockholm, SWEDEN.

Kühnen, U., Haberstroh, S., Öberst, A., \& \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (January, 2011).  The conversational basis of ease of retrieval effects. Poster presented at the 12th Annual Conference of the Society for Personality and Social Psychology, San Antonio, TX.
\years{2006} \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Andersen, S. M., Kooij, C., \& Schneidmesser, E. (May, 2006).  Significant-other representations influence intergroup perceptions. Poster presented at the 18th Annual Conference of the Association for Psychological Science, New York, NY.

Uleman, J. S., \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Rim, S., \& Gorman, J. P. (May, 2006).  Processing goals affect control over the influence of implicit impressions. Poster presented at the 18th Annual Conference of the Association for Psychological Science, New York, NY.

\textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, Uleman, J. S., Rim, S., \& Gorman, J. P. (January, 2006).  The imperviousness of behavior interpretations to vague suspicions. Poster presented at the 7th Annual Conference of the Society for Personality and Social Psychology, Palm Springs, CA.
\years{2003} \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.}, \& Ataca, B. (July, 2003). Individualism-collectivism, self-concept clarity, and self-esteem. Poster presented at the 6th European Regional Congress of the International Association for Cross-Cultural Psychology, Budapest, Hungary.
\years{2001} \textbf{Sarıbay, S. A.} (July, 2001) Kurt Lewin: His metatheory and its evaluation in terms of the ten fundamental issues. Poster presented at the 7th European Congress of Psychology, London, UK.
\endgroup

\section*{Invited Colloquia}
\subsection*{Academic}
\years{2014} Charles University, Prague, CZECH REPUBLIC (October)
\years{2013} 18th National Psychology Students Congress, Izmir University of Economics, TURKEY (July)
\years{2011} Middle East Technical University, TURKEY (June)
\years{2009} Koç University, TURKEY (October)
\years{2008} Columbia Business School, NY, USA (April)

National Chengchi University, Taipei, TAIWAN (April)

Gettysburg College, PA, USA (February)

Hong Kong University of Science and Technology, HONG KONG (February)

Singapore Management University, SINGAPORE (January)

National Cheng-Kung University, Tainan, TAIWAN (January)  

\subsection*{Industry \& Organizations}
\years{2016} Psikolojik açıdan “mobbing”: Tanımı, özellikleri ve oluşma zemini. İş Vereni Yakan Sorular 5, Datassist
\years{2015} Trust and Leadership. EnerjiSA
\years{2014} Sosyal-bilişsel açıdan değerlendirmenin zorluğu. Değerlendiriciler Zirvesi, İş Bankası

\section*{Professional Activities}
\subsection*{Ad-hoc Reviewer}
Basic and Applied Social Psychology, European Journal of Social Psychology, Journal of Community and Applied Social Psychology, Journal of Experimental Social Psychology, Journal of Personality \& Social Psychology, Personality \& Social Psychology Bulletin, Psychonomic Bulletin \& Review, Polish Psychological Bulletin, Scandinavian Journal of Psychology, Self \& Identity, Social Justice Research

\subsection*{Consulting Reviewer}
\years{2013-present} Türk Psikoloji Yazıları [Turkish Psychological Articles]

\subsection*{Grant Reviewer}
\years{2014,2015} Panel Judge and Project Consultant, Scientific and Technological Research Council of Turkey, Social Sciences and Humanities Research Grant Committee (TÜBİTAK-SOBAG)
\years{2013, 2014} External Assessor in Psychology Committee,  Insight Grants Program, SSHRC (Canada)
\years{2013} External Consultant, Scientific and Technological Research Council of Turkey, Social Sciences and Humanities Research Grant Committee (TÜBİTAK-SOBAG)


\subsection*{Committees}
\years{2012} 17th National Congress of Psychology, Administrative Committee \& Scientific Committee Member


\section*{Administrative Duties}

\years{2013-present} Faculty of Arts and Sciences, Faculty Executive Committee, Assoc. Prof. Representative
\years{2011-2015} Psychology Ethics Subcommittee, Executive Member
\years{2012-2015} Department of Psychology, Vice Chair
\years{2013} Faculty of Arts and Sciences, Faculty Council, Asst. Prof. Representative


\section*{Teaching}

Undergraduate: Social Psychology, Experimental Psychology, History of Psychology, Research Methods

Graduate: Social Psychology, Research Methods \& Statistics, Social Psychology of Organizations


%\hrule
\section*{Grants, Honors \& Awards}
\noindent
\years{2013}Excellence in Research Award, BÜVAK (Boğaziçi University Foundation)
\years{2011}Internal research grant, "Psychological Bases of Conservatism," Boğaziçi University
\years{2008-2010}Postdoctoral Fellowship, Bremen International Graduate School of Social Sciences
\years{2002-2007}MacCracken Fellowship, New York University
\years{2000}Ranked 2nd among graduating class, Middle East Technical University

%\vspace{1cm}
\vfill{}
%\hrulefill

\begin{center}
{\scriptsize  Last updated: \today\- •\- 
% ---- PLEASE LEAVE THIS BACKLINK FOR ATTRIBUTION AS PER CC-LICENSE
Typeset in \href{http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex}{
%\fontspec{Times New Roman}
\XeTeX }\\
% ---- FILL IN THE FULL URL TO YOUR CV HERE
\href{http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex}{http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result of the changed code]

Comment: This works, although yes, there is that space.  But the another answer provided a method if I wanted to fill that space with part of the doi.  \hfill\\ is quicker thought, so I preferred that.  Thank you.  Btw, what does MWE mean?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell LaTeX where it is allowed to break these doi numbers by inserting `\-` where appropriate:

```
doi:\-10.1111/\-j.1751-\-9004.2012.00452.x
```

Comment: Thank you, this works thought I preferred \hfill\\ because it's quicker.